# perl's print shows nothing when printing one variable

Tags: perl

I test below two examples

```
perl -e '$a="root";$b=$a=~m/root/;print("$b");'
```

it output nothing, while

```
perl -e '$a="root";$b=$a=~m/root/;print("$b,$b");'
```

output `1,1`

I don't understand why the first code line output nothing?

Comment: The first example prints `1` when I run it (with no trailing newline, which might make it difficult to read). Try: `perl -e '$a="root";$b=$a=~m/root/;print("$b\n");'`

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh, I understand what is going on. I used fish shell. And the shell prompt eat my output, thank you so much

Comment: If you use `-l` switch, it will automatically append a newline character `\n` to whatever string you are printing. `perl -le '$a="root";$b=$a=~m/root/;print("$b");'`